# Cannot assign a value of type [Address] to a value of type [Address]?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a class `Address` that's a pretty simple metadata container. (At bottom.)

I *have* an array of `Address` objects that is not an optional - it's definitely there. I also have a class that maintains an optional list of these refs, like so:

```
public class Person {
    public var addresses : [Address]?
    ...
}
```

So when I have these items, I'm using:

```
if let theAddresses = backgroundTask.result {
    person.addresses = theAddresses
}
```

Which seems fairly straightforward - but for whatever reason, I have a compiler error on the assignment of `person.addresses`:

```
Cannot assign a value of type '[Address]' to a value of type '[Address]?'
```

Which seems unreasonable. What can I check or experiment with to determine what's going on here?

**This is with Xcode 6.4.**

```
public class Address {
    public let streetNum: Int
    public let streetName: String
    public let city: String
    public let state: String
    public let zip: String
}
```

The source code for `BackgroundTask`:

```
public class BackgroundTask<T> {
    public var result: T?
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the interface for `backgroundTask`'s type? I'm trying to reproduce the error in a Playground.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the code you posted.

Comment: IMO, it should work.  Did you try to clean up the product (menu Product -> Clean) and rebuild?  Otherwise, indeed, what's the interface of backgroundTask?

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: If possible, I would use structs, not classes, to represent `Person` and `Address`

Comment: Additional code posted - thanks folks.

Comment: Still can't reproduce.  How is `backgroundTask` instantiated?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. I assumed that `backgroundTask` was instantiated like this: `let backgroundTask = BackgroundTask<[Address]>()`.

Comment: Found it - my own mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew - figured it out. This was occurring after a large-ish refactoring, and the `Address` class existed in two different modules - the iOS application module, as well as the embedded framework.

It was intended for the embedded framework, so I removed it from the 'Compiled Sources' section of the iOS application, and everything's solid.

Seems two different "versions" of the class were being used depending on where they were being referenced/returned.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov mmmmmhm.

Comment: Classic. Glad you found it.